# Angular 2 redirect from child router

Tags: angular2-routing

I have `appRoutes` in my Angular 2 app

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    {
        path: 'component-two', component: AppComponent2,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        ]
    },
];
```

How I can redirect from my `LoginComponent` to `HomeComponent`?

Answer (score 1):

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,
    children: [
           { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
           { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
              ]
}
];
```

You have to do this.

Comment: what is it? You can writing full code !? I must have starting page /login.. and not /home

Answer (score 0):

you should use `redirectTo` for default redirect

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '/login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '/home', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

from Html you can redirect like

```
<nav>
    <a routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
    <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
  </nav>
```

inject `Router` to your **HomeComponent's** constructor

```
constructor(
  private router: Router,
  private service: HeroService
) {}
```

Then use  `this.router.navigate(['/login']);` in your event function

for more details refer [angular guide](https://angular.io/guide/router)